# How to reapply validators to formControl having same name

Tags: angular, angular-validation, angular-validator

We have a form that have same formControlName for two fields. Only one field is visible at a time and validators are applied by below logic  -

```
  let validators: ValidatorFnUtil[] = [];
  validators.push(CustomValidators.validateNumberGreaterThanZero); //custom validators
   const control = this.accountForm.get('shares');
  control.setValidators(validators);
  control.updateValueAndValidity();
```

in template -

```
<mat-form-field  >
  <mat-label>{{ 'quantity' | translate }}</mat-label>
  <input
    type="number"
    formControlName="shares"
    matInput
  />
  <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.shares">{{
    formErrors.shares | translate
  }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

When form is loaded, we set the validator for the fields and it works as required.It verifies if the field is having negative value and highlights the field.The second field is visible when perform a slider and previous field gets hide.Now for this new field, validators don't work. If toggle back to previous state, it works for previous field.

Comment: Why hide/show the field when it's in reality the same field and values is going to be stored in the same place?

Comment: it is due to business requirement, we need to store multiple shares belonging to multiple accounts while we use slider. UI changes to support formArray in place standalone element.